# Obfuscating Secrets from Query History

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Asking on behalf of a Snowflake client:

> If we wanted to build a table with some hashed values using a secret
>   to add some entropy (i.e., a pepper), is there a way to execute that
>   SQL in a way that obfuscates the secret from things like the query
>   history?

Answer (score 1):

By default, most roles can only see query history for statements that were executed by the same role.  Assuming that they are not trying to hide this query from accountadmin role (which has access to SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE), then I'd recommend executing that query as a role that other users don't have access to.  Then, they won't see it.

Answer (score 0):

One more option -- Put the secret in a UDF.  The UDF will appear in the query history, but not the secret.